# Getting an error in C++ using vector and struct

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, struct

What is the error in this code:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct symtab{
  string name;
  string location;
};
vector<symtab> symtab_details;

bool search_symtab(string s){

  if (find (symtab_details.begin(), symtab_details.end(), s)!=symtab_details.end()) return true;
  return false;
}


int main() {

    bool get = search_symtab("ADD");
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algo.h:166:17: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘symtab’ and ‘const std::basic_string’)
>       if (*__first == __val)

Comment: The `find` function tries to find a `symtab` structure in your vector. Learn about [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) for *one* way of solving your problem.

Comment: overload operator== in your symtab class so that it can be compared to a const std::string &

Comment: The error is quite clear. If you don't understand why it's an error, please read more about operator overloading before opening questions about it, as it is a pretty fundamental feature of the language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are trying to find a `std::string`, `"ADD"`, in a `std::vector<symtab>`. Of course that won't work.

What you need is [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

```
auto it = std::find_if(symtab_details.begin(),
                       symtab_details.end(),
                       [&s](symtab const& item) { return item.name == s; });
return  (it != symtab_details.end());
```

Comment: @Debian_yadav, you need to compile using a C++11 compiler. E.g. if you use `g++`, you can use `-std=c++11` in the command line to compile your program as a C++11 program.

Comment: I am using g++ compiler

Comment: @Debian_yadav, use `-std=c++11` then.

Comment: But I am having linker problem in gcc

Comment: @Debian_yadav, that was a typo on my part. Use `g++ -std=c++11`.

Answer (score 3):

The code is searching for an object of type `symtab` that matches an object of type `std::string`. So you have to provide a comparison operator to tell whether a particular `symtab` object is equal to a particular `std::string` object. You need

```
bool operator==(const symtab&, const std::string&);
```

If you read the error message carefully that's what it's telling you.